# How to look for values in database and return an array of values

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to search a MySQL database for specific values and put these in an array.

The contacts table has `name`,`email`,`group`,`Phone`...

I would like to search the database by group and return the email adresses in an array, separated by `,` (comma) to use further in my code.

What is the best way to do this?

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Group='Group 1'") 
    or die(mysqli_error()); 

...

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) 
    {
         array ( row->email,...)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way of what I was trying to do. I needed a selectbox with values from the database.

```
....

 $query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE category='$category' AND stelplaats='$stelplaats'");

echo '<td><select name ="collega" required>';
echo '<option value"">---</option>';
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array( $query ))
{
    echo '<option value =" '.$row2['id'].'"';
    echo '>'.$row2['name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select></td></tr>';
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have different options beginning with:

1. Update your select query to only display the email, if you don't require the other fields this is the way to go
2. In your loop just add only the email field to the array

   $dataArray[] = $row->email;

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT email FROM Contacts WHERE Group='Group 1'") 
    or die(mysqli_error()); 

$emailArray = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) 
{
     array_push($emailArray,$row->email);
}
$responseEmail = implode(",", $emailArray);
```

Hope this will works!